# iOS 5: unable to use "pass by reference" pattern using NSError

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

I'm experiencing a strange issue related to "pass by reference" pattern, in my code each time I call a method like:

```
[foo doSomethingWithError:&error];
```

it freezes my app... no exception is raised!
If I replace **&error** with **nil**, the code execution can then proceed... but why? It works has expected in iOS 4+

I also tried to use **__autoreleasing** for error (as documented by apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/_index.html), but I'm unable to fix the issue :(

ps: I'm using **ARC**

EDIT:

this is an example of method that causes a freeze:

```
- (BOOL)loadData { 
    NSError *error = nil;
    if ([self.fetchController performFetch:&error]) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        GTMLoggerDebug(@"Data loaded!");
        return YES;
    } else {
        GTMLoggerDebug(@"Error while fetching data: %@", [error description]);
        return NO;
    }
}
```

the method is called in **viewDidLoad**, but it doesn't work neither in **viewDidAppear**.

**fetchController** is declared as:

```
@property (readonly, strong) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchController;
```

Some test I used in loadData (all passed):

```
NSAssert(self.fetchController != nil, @"NO FETCH CONTROLLER");
NSAssert([self.fetchController respondsToSelector:@selector(performFetch:)], @"CAN'T FETCH?!");
NSAssert(self.fetchController.managedObjectContext != nil, @"invalid context");
NSAssert(self.fetchController.fetchRequest != nil, @"invalid fetchRequest");
NSAssert(self.fetchController.delegate != nil, @"invalid delegate");
NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"NOT MAIN THREAD!");
```

then in **viewDidLoad**:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES/NO];
```

...but nothing... it does not work... or better, it works very very rarely :(

**SOLVED!**

**After hours of tests and reasoning about it, I realized that the real problem was related to  core data. I was using an NSManagedObjectContext shared between threads, and since context are NOT thread safe, I was experiencing these strange issues!**

Comment: How are you assigning error? What is the method declaration of doSomething...?

Comment: The first time in my code is: [self.fetchController performFetch:&error], but that's not the point, if I pass nil and my code proceed in the execution, I will get the same problem later as soon as I encounter a [foo doSomethingWithError:&error];  :(

Comment: Show us the implementation of `-doSomethingWithError:`

Comment: it's the implementation of NSFetchedResultsController (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFetchedResultsController/performFetch:), not my own implementation

Comment: So post some actual code that is causing the problem...

Comment: I am having the same problem, and also with the nil works! I am going to dig into the CoreData stuff! thanks for posting your answer!